# Weird characters when trying to get sha1 certificate android

Tags: android, certificate, command-prompt, sha1

I currently trying to get a SHA1 certificate for android, but it results in weird characters appearing at my command prompt screen. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

is there something wrong at my computer's settings? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!!

In case anyone gets stuck on this, I would solve this as below:

Just replace **`-exportcert`** to **`-list -v`**

```
 keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path-to-key-store>/debug.keystore
```

This is somehow related to an encoding issue with **exportcert**. You can read more about it here: [keytool -exportcert encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54917937/)

Answer (score -1):

Forget all the things to find SHA1 Key .
The best solution for generating SHA1 key for android is from android studio.
Just follow the easy steps as below.

1. Click on Gradle on far right side.
2. Click on refresh icon and after refresh you will see the name of the app.
3. Click on the Tasks -> Report -> Signing Report.
4. Find the SHA1 Key on bottom part in console.

Comment: This does not solve the OP question. The question specifically asks for generating SHA1 fingerprint from debug.keystore using command line.