# keytool -exportcert encoding issue

Tags: android, ssh-keys, keytool

Regarding to this article [article](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) I'm trying to generate debug certificate.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

give a follow result:
[image]

where expected is somthing like this:

```
Certificate fingerprint: SHA1: DA:39:A3:EE:5E:6B:4B:0D:32:55:BF:EF:95:60:18:90:AF:D8:07:09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Run this command you will get your sha-1 key.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

> keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore"
>   -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: Here is another solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode